# Infinitude of odd primes of the form $4n+3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I have read in a book proof regarding the infinitude of primes of the form $4n+3$. The issue is there are missing steps (as per the understanding level of mine),
 and want to get the 'filled missing steps' vetted (highlighted by $\color {blue}{\textrm{blue color}}$).
 Will ask doubts, when am unable to understand text. 
For comparison, an image of the book's proof is given. 
 
 It starts with the statement that: 
Any odd prime is either of the form $4n+1$ or $4n+3$ for suitable $n \in \mathbb{
Z}$. 
For later requirement, it is shown 'earlier' that product for two odd integers, of the form $4n+1$ is also of the same form, as repeated below: 
> Let two primes be $4n_1+1, 4n_2+1$ with the product being : $(4n_1+1)(4n_2+1) = 4(4n_1n_2 + n_1+n_2) + 1$, i.e. of the same form.

Next, it shows infinitude of primes for the $4n+3$ form by contradiction approach, by assuming a finite number ($N$) of such primes $p_1,p_2, p_3, ..., p_N$ being of the form $4n+3$ in ascending order, with $p_1=3, p_2=7,$ $p_3=11, p_4=15$, etc. 
 Hence, the product of such primes (let, $M$) would also be of the same form. Let $$M = 4(p_2p_3...p_N)+3$$

> > Doubt 1: Why $p_1$ is removed just for the sake of it being divisible by $3$? Will it not affect the value of $M$?

Next, it states that by Theorem 9, $M$ is not divisible by any of $p_2, p_3, ..., p_N$.

> > Doubt 2: That proof considers all factors $p_1p_2p_3....p_N$ (i.e. not ignores $p_1$),

takes $M =p_1p_2p_3....p_N+1$, and relies on division of $M$ and $p_1p_2p_3...p_N$ by a (among the N possible) factor, let $p_1$. 
Then shows by contradiction that the left side ($\frac{M}{p_1} - p_2p_3...p_N$ is an integer, while the r.h.s. ($\frac{1}{p_1}$) is not an integer.

Further, $3\nmid M$, as $3\nmid 4$, $\color {blue}{\textrm{as in the equality $M - 4(p_2p_3...p_N) =3$, both terms on the l.h.s.}}$
$\color {blue}{\textrm{need be divisible by $3$.}}$

Hence, $M$ has the form $4n+3$, but no prime factor among $p_2, p_2, p_N$. The alternate form left for prime factors of $M$ is $4n+1$.

But, the product of such prime factors has already been shown to be of the form $4n+1$, rather than the form of $M$, i.e. $4n+3$.

Hence, by contradiction, there are an infinite number of primes of the form $4n+3$.

> > Doubt 3: Does the author take that all numbers of the form 4n+3 are odd primes? If so, then should have indicated that. Does he expect the reader to provide a proof of the same? I mean that for me saying that there are infinitely many primes of the form 4n+3, is different from saying that: 'all' numbers of the given form are prime. Also, what about the numbers of the form 4n+1. Are those also same for the primality criteria as 4n+3?

Have found very good links on MSE, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2062236/understanding-infinite-primes-of-form-4n3?rq=1), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627738/proof-infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-4k-3-origin-of-4p-1-p-k-1), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244915/infinitely-number-of-primes-in-the-form-4n1-proof?rq=1), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1621324/infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-3k2), & [also here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2405649/proof-that-there-are-infinitely-many-prime-numbers-of-the-form-3k1?rq=1).

[image]

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21333/help-understand-the-proof-of-infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-4n3?rq=1

Comment: @daniel Hope it would be very informative, particularly (may be, only) answer by 'Number', that points to many further links. Have just started, will ask you for doubts when stuck.

Comment: Doubt 1: We want a number that is not divisible by $p_1$ through $p_n$.  We want it in the form of $4K + 3$.  So we do *NOT* want $3|K$ because then $3$ *would* divide $4K+3$.  As all the *other* primes do not divide $3$ we can assure $p_k$ does not divide $4K + 3$ by assuring that $p_k$ *DOES* divide $K$.  Sk $M = 4p_2p_3... p_n + 3$ is a number of the form that is not divisible by any of the primes.  It may not be the only such number but it was a simple and easy one to derive.

Comment: Doubt 2:  $p_1 = 3$ and $3\not \mid M = 4K +3$ because $3$ does *NOT* divide $K$ or $4$ but $3$ *DOES* divide $3$ so $p_1 \not \mid M =4K +3$.  All the other primes work in the exact *opposite* manner.  $p_k$ *does* divide $K$ but NOT $3$ so $p_k \not \mid 4K + 3$.  so $p_1, p_2,....p_n$ do NOT divide $4K +3$ but the reasons the pries that aren't $3$ don't, is a different reason than why $3$ doesn't.  But the important bit is that *none* of them do divide it.

Comment: Doubt 3: "Does the author take that all numbers of the form $4n+3$ are odd primes?"  Not at all! Not even remotely!  As  we are assuming there are finite prime 4n+3, and there are infinite $4n+3$ there *MUST* be infinitely many *composite* $4n+3$.  No-where does he assume that $4n+3$ are prime.  But he has proven that all number of the form must has a prime factor that is of the form $4n + 3$.  So if $4n+3$ is *not* prime then $4n+3 = N*p_j$ where $p_j = 4m + 3$.

Comment: "Also, what about the numbers of the form 4n+1. Are those also same for the primality criteria as 4n+3?"  No.  As $(4n + 3)(4m + 3) = 4(4mn+3m+3n + 2) + 1$ it does not folllow that a number of the form $4n + 1$ must have prime factors of the form $4n+1$.  So we can not prove it this way.

Comment: You *can* prove there are infinitely many primes of the form $4n+1$ by a similar method, along with a number-theoretic trick...  If you have any finite list of such primes $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n$, then consider $N = 4 p_1^2 p_2^2 \cdots p_n^2 + 1$.  Then any prime factor of $N$ cannot be in the list $p_1, \ldots, p_n$; and also, such a prime factor $p$ would have to be odd, and it would also have -1 being a quadratic residue $\pmod{p}$, which implies $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doubt 1: We are *defining* $M$ by this expression. There is no reason we can't choose to omit $3$ from the product in the definition.

Doubt 2: Not quite sure I understand what you're saying here. Yes, it is true that $M$ must not be divisible by any of the $3, p_2,\ldots p_N$ since its first term is divsible by $p_2\ldots p_N$ but not by $3$ and its second term is divisble by $3$ but not any of the $p_2\ldots p_N$.

Doubt 3: No the author does not assume all numbers of the form $4n+3$ are prime. Why do yo think they do? They prove there are infinitely many primes of that form by assuming there are finitely many and deriving a contradiction. I don't get what you're asking regarding $4n+1,$ but there are an infinite number of primes of that form as well.

I think you are missing some essential part of the logic here, but I can't tell what it is. Feel free to ask follow-up questions.

Comment: Thanks for the same, but have many issues. Starting, with the most direct, can $M$  be chosen in any way we like. If so, what is the justification for that. Also, can there be any primes chosen, say : $M = p_2p_5p_6p_9\cdots p_{n-2}p_n$.

Comment: @jiten The logic of the proof is 1) Assume for the sake of contradiction that there are a finite number of primes of the form $4n+3.$ Call them $p_1=3,$ $p_2=7,$ $p_3=11,$ and so on till the last one $p_n.$ 2) Define the number $M=4p_2p_3\ldots p_n+3.$ (We can make any definition we want... we make this one cause leads to the contradiction.) 3) By its construction, this number is not divisible by any of the $p_i,$ is odd and moreover, is of the form $4n+3.$ But this is impossible. Hence our assumption that there are a finite number of primes of the form $4n+3$ was wrong.

Comment: @jiten Have you understood the Euclid proof that there are an infinite number of primes? This is very similar (at least to the version that is a proof by contradiction).

Comment: Thanks for that.  Yes, I have understood Euclid proof. But the approach (for this OP) should then be extendable to general cases as $8k+7$ too, where $p_1=3, p_2=5,p_3=7$, can we delete the middle (not the end term, as $p_1$ in the OP's case) term, i.e. $p_3$? This is my doubt #1 crux.

Comment: @jiten Huh? Again, you can construct *any number you want*.... whether or not it produces the desired contradiction is another story. (And no, not all instances of Dirichlet's theorem can be proved in an elementary way like this.)

Comment: Sorry, I had to take the response to a generalized form; but was unable to explain the issue(doubt) without that. I mean how the first term $p_1=3$ can be deleted. Can the same be done for $p_3=7$ for $8k+7$ too, Else, why it is possible and valid here to delete $p_1$, but not $p_3$.

Comment: Please do not misconstrue me, I am just asking for the reason why $p_1$ deletion would not affect the representation of $M$. It is simply confusing without some logical basis, as to which terms can be deleted and which not. Can I just delete any? or can do it from the left end only? And is it having any logical basis or theorem for it.

Comment: For $8k+7,$ you could attempt a similar proof as follows: 1) Assume for the sake of contradiction that $p_1=7,p_2=23,p_3=31,\ldots p_n$ are all of the primes of the form $8k+7.$ 2) Consider $M=8p_2p_3\ldots p_n + 7.$ By its construction and our assumptions it is not divisible by any primes of the form $8k+7.$ Thus (since it is odd) it must be a product of primes of the form $8k+1,$ $8k+3,$ $8k+5.$ Does this produce a contradiction like before? That depends on whether you can write a number of the form $8k+7$ as a product of numbers of the form $8k+1,$ $8k+3,$ and $8k+5.$

Comment: @jiten You are not *deleting* anything. You are *considering* some number. We could consider the number $M=p_n +15.$ Or the number $M= 5*p_1 = 15.$ It's just that those two don't happen to produce a useful contradiction.

Comment: If take by congruence arithmetic, that all the odd primes fall into one of the four classes: $8k+1, 8K+3, 8k+5, 8k+7$, then $(8k+3)(8k'+5)$ is of the form $8k''+7$. And the product of all the three $(8k+1, 8k+3, 8k+5)$ is of the form $8k+7$.

Comment: @jiten Yes, that's right. So our attempt to generalize the proof to the case $8k+7$ is not successful. $M=8\cdot 23\cdot 31\ldots p_n+7$ could be a product of primes of the form $(8k+3)$ and $(8k+5)$ and there's no obvious reason why that would be contradictory. This is in contrast to the case in the proof above, where it is impossible for $M$ to be a product of primes of the form $4k+1$ since it is of the form $4k+3.$

Comment: So, this is the logic from which the answer comes rather than me going (in reverse) after removing in general case (i.e. $8k+7$) the middle terms. Thanks for that a lot. I hope you will elaborate your response a bit more, particularly the part: "why that would be contradictory".

Comment: @jiten I don't know what needs elaboration but I'll try. In the $4k+3$ case $M$ was manifestly of the form $4k+3$ so it could not be the product of primes of the form $4k+1.$ There is no similar argument to make in the $8k+7$ case... For that one, by analogy we designed $M$ so it was manifestly of the form $8k+7$ and yet not divisible by any primes of the form $8k+7.$ But there is no problem here since it's possible to make a number of the form $8k+7$ by multiplying primes not of the form $8k+7.$ It is impossible to make a number of the form $4k+3$ by multiplying primes not of the form $4k+3.$

Comment: Re: We can get $8n+1$ by $(8k+3)(8j+3)$ or by $(8k+7)(8j+7)$ so we can't prove there are inf primes of form $8n+1$.  We can get $8n + 5$ by $(8k+3)(8j+7)$ so we can't prove for form $8n+5$ and we can get $8n+7$ by $(8k+3)(8j+5)$ so we cant prove for form $8n+7$.  But the only way to get $8n+3$ is but $(8k+1)(8j+3)$.  So any number of the form $8n+3$ must have a factor of the form $8n+3$.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for this comment. It is really life saver. I feel sometimes a clear-cut summary that covers also a few possible cases is better to understand.

Comment: @fleablood Minor correction: you can get $(8k+3)$ from $(8m+7)(8n+5)$ (1,3,5,7 mod 8 are Klein 4 group).

Comment: @fleablood In fact, are $3n+2,$ $4n+3$ and $6n+5$ the only examples that work here?

Comment: I'd call that more than minor.  It means we can't do this line or argument for primes of form $8n +k$.

Answer (score 1):

Doubt 1: The number M is simply defined to be the product of all of the primes of the form 4n+3 except for 3. M doesn't need to be the product of all primes of that form: we simply need an impossible thing to prove by contradiction. M should exist as defined, yet it has impossible properties.

Doubt 2: $p_2,..,p_N$ are not devisors by the earlier theorem. 3 is not  a divisor since the definition of M that spawned doubt 1 makes it so (i.e 3 is not a factor of $4(p_1...p_n)$, it will not be a factor of the number three larger than this)

I think the doubts come from the assumption that M must include all primes of the form 4n+3 when in fact it is just a number suitable for he proof

Comment: It is the subset of possible values that $M$ can take which is the issue (i.e., doubt #1). If $M$ can take a subset of values, then should it take only consecutive values, or can it take any values - say: product of 2nd, 4th, 7th, 11th, and so on randomly?

Comment: M can be any number you want so long as it has the following conditions:  1)  M is of the form $4n+3$.  2) M is *not* divisible by $3, p_2, p_3,..... p_n$.  $4p_2p_3...p_n + 3$ is one such number.  $13*4*p_2..p_n + 3$ is another.  If $n$ is even then $3p_2... p_n + 2$ is a third.  If $n$ is odd then $p_2....p_n+ 6$ is also one.  However for sake of simplicity the number $M = 4p_2p_3....p_n + 3$ is the easiest and clearest to work with.

Comment: The thing is you have to *come up* with a number $M$ and then *justify* is satisfies those two conditions.  The heart of this proof is proving that such an $M$ actually exists.  The easiest such number to derive and prove satisfies the two conditions is $M = 4p_2...p_n + 3$.  It's obviously of the form $4M + 3$ and obviously $3$ does not divide it.  And obviously none of the $p_k$ divide it.  It's not the *only* such number but ... well, it's the most obvious such number.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be go to first go over outline or proof without proving the details.

1)  An odd number has odd prime factors.

2) All odd numbers are either of the form $4n + 1$ or $4n + 3$.

3) If a composite number has only prime factors of the form $4n+1$ then that composite number is of the form $4n+1$.

3a) There for if a number is of the form $4n + 3$ it must have a prime factor of the form $4n + 3$.

4) If $p_2,..., p_n$ are prime and none are $3$ then $M = 4p_2...p_n + 3$ is not divisible by *any* of the $p_k$ and $M$ is not divisible by $3$.

4a) So either $M = 4p_2 .... p_n + 3$ is prime, or its prime factors are all *different* primes from $3, p_2,.... p_n$.

5) assume there are only finitely many primes of the form $4n+3$.

5a) so we can list them  $3, p_2, p_3 .... p_n$

6) Consider $M = 4p_2,p_3... p_n + 3$.

7) By 3a) $M$ must have a prime factor of the form $4n + 3$.

7b) By 4) $3, p_2, p_3, ... p_n$ are not prime factors of $M$.

7c) So the prime factor of the form $4n + 3$ is not one of the primes $3, p_2, p_3, .... p_n$.

8) This contradicts that 5a) was a list of all the prime factors of the form $4n+3$.

=====

Okay, final time:

Claim:  There are more than $7$ primes of the form $4n + 3$ and the primes $3, 7, 13,17,29,37,41$ are not all the primes of the form $4n+3$.

Proof:

Lemma:  All numbers of the form $4n+3$ have a prime factor of the form $4n+3$.

Proof:  Suppose not.  Let $N=4n+3$ have a prime factorization of $\prod q_i^{a_i}$ and none of the $q_i= 4n+3$.  As the $q_i$ are odd they must all be of the form $4n_i + 1$.  By induction and several multiplications $\prod q_i^{a_i} = \prod (4n_i + 1)^{a_i} = 4M + 1$ so $N$ is not of the form $4n+3$. QED  Lemma.

Now, consider then number $M = 4*(7*13*17*29*37*41)+3$. $M$ is of the form $4n + 3$ so by the Lemma, $M$ must have a prime factor, $q$ of the form $4n+3$.

What is $q$.

It can't be $3$ because: $3\not \mid M$ because $3|3$ but $3\not \mid 4*(7*13*17*29*37*41)$

It can't be $7$ because: $7\not \mid M$ because $7|4*(7*13*17*29*37*41)$ but $7\not \mid 3$

It can't be $13$ because: $13\not \mid M$ because $7|4*(7*13*17*29*37*41)$ but $13\not \mid 3$

It can't be $17$ because: $17\not \mid M$ because $7|4*(7*13*17*29*37*41)$ but $17\not \mid 3$

It can't be $29$ because: $29\not \mid M$ because $7|4*(7*13*17*29*37*41)$ but $29\not \mid 3$

It can't be $37$ because: $37\not \mid M$ because $7|4*(7*13*17*29*37*41)$ but $37\not \mid 3$

It can't be $41$ because: $41\not \mid M$ because $7|4*(7*13*17*29*37*41)$ but $41\not \mid 3$

So it must be some prime of the form $4n+3$ that is *not* $3, 7, 13,17,29,37,41$

So $3, 7, 13,17,29,37,41$ are *not* all the primes of the form $4n +3$.  There must be others.

QED Claim:

So instead of proving there are more than $7$ primes, prove that for any number $n$ there are more than $m$ primes.  Do it the *EXACT* same way.  *IF* $3, p_2, ....., p_m$ were the *ONLY* primes of the form $4n+3$ then then number $M = 4(p_2....p_m) +3$ must have a prime factor of the  form $4n+3$ that is *different* than all $3, p_2,....., p_m$.  So there must be more than $m$ primes of the form $4n+3$.  As there are more primes of the form than any $m$, there are infinitely many primes of the form.

BTW:  $M = 4*(7*13*17*29*37*41)+3  =272228687$ is a prime number. And it is in the form of $4n+3$.

So now we know there are at least eight primes of the form $4n+3$.

If we consider $4*(7*13*17*29*37*41*272228687)+3$ we will be able to find a ninth.

.... indeed... $74108457209057911 = 271 × 273462941730841$ and $271$ is of the form $4n+3$.  We can do this all day.

Comment: Thanks a lot. A doubt is: why all factors in the representation of $M$ are of the same form. I have checked that if take a finite number $N$, then for $N=5,6,7$ the residue class of M (whether or not it includes $p_1$) has no guarantee to be in any particular one. It varies for different values of $N$. So, why only one form of factors are being taken up? Why not state (at the risk of failing the contradiction approach) that if $N$ is an odd value, then all factors (starting with $p_2$) are of the form $4k+3$; else need an even number of factors of form $4k+1$ & the rest $4k+3$.

Comment: It seems that I have misunderstood: actually proof says that it should not be possible to have all factors of other form (here 4k+1). There must be a factor of the form $4k+3$. But, when the $N$ is odd, then definitely "all" factors 'can' be of the form $4k+3$. This logic would not work for the $8k+7$, as product of an equal number of $8k+3, 8k+5$ classes factors can create a factor of the form $8k+7$. So, in that case it is possible that $8k+7$ term is simply not there in the list of $N$ factors. However, in this case it is not possible to have NONE of factors of the form $4k+3$.

Comment: The line of argument chosen that removes "somehow" chances of divisibility by $3$, is not good. A better approach could be (please modify, as incomplete) : "Can take instead of all prime factors available in the finite set of size $N$, a proper subset that excludes $3$ without affecting applicability of Euclid's approach to prove that the subset is not divisible by any of the prime factors in it ". Also, would STILL request why only a proper subset is enough for the same, as you have stated much earlier (in a comment for representation of $M$) that any subset of ascending primes can be taken.

Comment: And $3$ is !!!!!!!***NOT***!!!!!! excluded.  $3$, like *EVERY* other only of the $p_k$ does not divide $M$.  $3$ is absolutely, positively, and utterly *required* to be !!!!!!!!!!***IN***CLUDED!!!!!!!!

Comment: I am also confused about the fact that the product of all primes in $K$, of the form $4k+1$ in $M=4k+3$, has $K$ of the form $4k+1$, but still brings $M$ of the form $4k+3$. I have an example which states this: Let, there be a total of two factors, with both terms of the form $4k+1$, with $k=3,4$ then $M=4((4k+1)(4k'+1))+3 => 4(16kk'+4k'+4k+1)+3$$=> 4(192+4(7)+1)+3 => 4(221)+3$. Here, $K=4*55+1$, but $M$ has the same form.

Comment: "So, I again request to make your last edit more clear."  And it doesn't occur to you to make your question more clear?  I have no idea what your objection or concern is.  And I have no idea which of your earler comments was not addressed.

Comment: I am not clear about your edit in OP, & is about the following: (i) "Where $p_j / \mod V_k$ we would have that none of the $p_j\mid M$ because $p_j \mid p_jk_j$ and $p_j∤V_k$". (ii) Also, why term-wise a series of (sum of) two terms are taken for $M$ is not clear?

Comment: When you are done with the comment exchange could you please delete those that are no longer needed. Or ping me, or flag a moderator to do it. There is a pending system flag on this post due to the shear number of comments (raised automatically when you get to comment #20), and we need to deal with it sooner or later.

Comment: I addressed i)  if $a|b$ and $a\not \mid c$ then $a\not \mid b+c$.  So if $p_k|4p_2p_3..p_n$ (which it obviously does) and $p_k\not \mid 3$ (which it obviously does not) then $p_k\not\mid 4p_2p_3..p_n+3=M$.  And as $3|3$ and $3\not\mid 4p_2p_3...p_2$ so $3\not\mid 4p_2p_3..p_n+3=M$.  ii) is utterly incoherent.

Comment: I meant "Also, why term-wise a series of (sum of) two terms are taken for M" is utterly incoherent.  I have absolutely NO idea what you mean by that.

Comment: If $a|b$ and $a\not \mid c$ then $a \not \mid b+c$ is a fundamental number theory proposition.  So $3\not \mid M$. (because $3|3$ but $3\not \mid 4p_2....p_n$).  And $p_2\not \mid M$. (because $p_2|4p_2....p_n$ but $p_2\not \mid 3$).  And $p_3\not\mid M$ (because $p_3|4p_2....p_n$ but $p_2\not \mid 3$.  And so on.  So *none* of $3, p_2, p_3,....,p_n$ divide $M$.

Comment: Can we enter a chat. Please create a chat room. Else, I have a chat room for a related discussion at: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72502/euclids-prime-infinitude-proof-adaptation.

Comment: "But, if my last comment were to be vetted, then no need (for me) to wait for any further chat there."  ???????  I have no idea what this means.

Comment: Please vet the logic as described by me for the shifting of multipliers from $K$ to $q$: Any prime factor multiplied to $3$, would produce an odd composite number divisible by $3$, this would lead to $K$ being again an odd composite number, and $4K$ being an even number. The sum $M=4K+3$ can be a prime or a composite, but adding a even composite ($4K$) to an odd composite ($q$) would anyway be an odd number. In fact, this scheme of shifting is a super-set of taking a subset of primes in $K$, in which instead of dropping prime factors, are multiplying to $q=3$.

Comment: @fleablood You must be thinking it is trivial, but for me not.

Comment: I think we've discussed it as far as we can.  The proof is before you.  And for the most part you understand it.There are some details thought processes as to how one can come up with it on one's own and how to adapt it true prove other things, but those are things a student must come to on his/her own with experience.